# Give empty input values a value only when they are empty/null, when a response function is executed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, null, conditional-operator

Otherwise, I want their original value.

**Basic desired outcome**: For this example, type a name to see the result. Erase the name and I want it to say "[empty]" instead of the name (in the text below the field). If I type the name again it should show the name again.

I am using "span" in a larger program so I used it in this example just in case, regardless the result should be the same.

EDIT: nevermind, this is false. The result is not the same. I need it to work when "span" is in the declared variable.

I am having a huge issue here. if/else statements are not working and I have tried all variations of ternary arguments.

I got this working halfway by doing the following after declaring nameHere, however, it would not return to having the inputted name value when it was entered:

```
var empty = null;
var nameHere = empty || "[empty]";
```

Here is some sample code of what I have right now:

```js
function getResponse() {
  var resultValue = "Hello my name is " + nameHere + ", nice to meet you.";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultValue;

  var nameHere = (nameHere === null) ? `<span>${"[EMPTY]"}</span>` : `<span>${document.getElementById("name").value}</span>`;
}
```

```html
<div class="formclass">
  <label for="name">Input name here</label>
  <input id="name" onchange="getResponse()"></input>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `nameHere` is being used before it's defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run following snippet. Once you type a name, it will be printed in the result div, once you erase EMPTY will be shown instead.

```js
function getResponse(){
      let val = document.getElementById("name").value
      if (!val.length) val = "[empty]";

      var resultValue = "Hello my name is " + val + ", nice to meet you.";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultValue;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="formclass">
      <label for="name">Input name here</label>
      <input id="name" onInput="getResponse()"></input>
 </div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You could keep `onInput` as `onchange`. Although `onInput` is more immediate.

Comment: Okay, so, this works when I do not include the " `<span>` " value when i declare the variable. I guess this is what I was ripping my hair out over. Is there any way for this to work when that <span> is in my declared variable?

Comment: I guess you mean something like this 
`var resultValue = "Hello my name is <span>" + val + "</span>, nice to meet you.";`

Comment: So I found both answers helpful, but what I just did was set `!val.length == 13` when I am assigning the value to an empty span. This was the most helpful in getting me there.

Comment: @Eduard Yes, I thought that might work as well. But I declared variables in another program this way and just did `"Hello I'm" + name + "..."` for ease of use/viewing due to the complexity

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Element.addEventListener()` method, you can use the event target to get the value.

```js
document.querySelector(`#name`).addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
  const val = event.target.value;
  const name = !val.length ? `<span>[EMPTY]</span>` : `<span>${val}</span>`;
  document.querySelector(`#result`).innerHTML = `Hello my name is ${name}, nice to meet you.`;
})
```

```html
<div class="formclass">
  <label for="name">Input name here</label>
  <input id="name" autoComplete="off">
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```